# Distribute Keys Dope Sheet

Tags: dopesheet

I would like to automate a few dope sheet keys animation, I setup the initial location of the elements and the end location:[image]

Now I need that they can be distributed between those frames 0 to 115 like these, created manually:
[image]

How can I achieve something more automted, I've tried to select only the first element and on keyboard hit G 115 (number of frames) /6 (divided thru 6, thats the number of elements and dont work), but the Delta X dont accept math calculations like that only numbers.

Comment: You need to press `=` before entering numbers to enable calculations, like `= G 115/6`

Comment: Ok, thank you it helps somehow. But still the question remains distributes all the key on that span of frames can be done without some kind of addon?